# Combine data from two or more field into one field in SAS Data Integration Studio

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I would like to combine data from multiple cells into one cell using **SAS Data Integration Studio**.

My data is divided into three different tables, as follows:

Table 1

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| City A | City B | City C |

Table 2

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| State A | State B | State C |

Table 3

| Variable 1 | Variable 2 |
| --- | --- |
| x | y |

Desired final table:

| Variable 1 | Variable 2 | States | Cities |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | State A, State B, State C | City A, City B, City C |

That is, I want to create a final table in which I can join the data from table 1 in just one field and the data from table 2 in another field, separating the respective values ​​with a comma.

Comment: Are you coding or looking for a GUI solution? It seems like a straightforward merge to me and use `CATX()` to combine the columns as needed.

Comment: @Reeza I am trying to code, but I am not succeeding, as I am quite new to SAS and I am having difficulty concatenating these variables, since the number of cities and states is unknow so I can't use mapping.